# Scala enumeration type fail in match/case

Tags: scala, enumeration

Enumerated values seem to fail in match/case expressions. This is what happens in a worksheet.

```
  object EnumType extends Enumeration {
    type EnumType = Value
    val a, b = Value
  }

  import EnumType._
  val x: EnumType = b                //> x : ... .EnumType.EnumType = b

  x match {
    case a => "a"
    case b => "b"
  }                                  //> res0: String = a

  if (x == a) "a" else "b"           //> res1: String = b
```

What's going on?  Thanks.

Comment: You should have gotten a warning that the 2nd `case` can never match, right?

Comment: That same code in a .scala file produces a warning, but not in a worksheet.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Like @Kevin Wright and @Lee just said, `a` and `b` work as variable patterns, not as `EnumType` values.

Another option to fix your code is making it explicit you are referencing values from the `EnumType` singleton:

```
scala> x match { case EnumType.a => "a" case EnumType.b => "b" }
res2: String = b
```

Answer (score 13):

The `a` and `b` in your `match` block aren't the same as the enumerated values `a` and `b`, the pattern matcher will simply match `x` in the first case and bind it to a new value `a` (the second case will be ignored)

To avoid this, you have two choices:

**1) wrap the values in backticks:**

```
x match {
  case `a` => "a"
  case `b` => "b"
}
```

**2) Make the enumerated values uppercase:**

```
object EnumType extends Enumeration {
  type EnumType = Value
  val A, B = Value
}

import EnumType._
val x: EnumType = B

x match {
  case A => "a"
  case B => "b"
}
```

Given that these values are (to all intents an purposes) constants, using uppercase is the more common/idiomatic solution.

Note that only the initial letter needs to be uppercase, not the name of the entire literal.

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware of either the Upper case or backtick convention for case statements.  (PS. I checked the checkmark indicating that the question was answered, but when I checked the checkmark on the the answer above, this answer became unchecked.)

Comment: Feel free to accept whatever rocks your boat the most :)  Incidentally, you can always change an accepted answer if something else comes along that you think is a better fit for the question.

Comment: I'd go also with making them uppercase anyway, respects the naming convention and also won't be treated as a value pattern in pattern matching

Answer (score 3):

`a` in your case statement is an unbound variable which matches anything. You need to explicitly check the value is equal to `a`:

```
x match {
    case v if v == a => "a"
    case _ => "b"
}
```

Comment: This is essentially the same as the if-expression version.

Comment: See the other two answers which also actually explain why it happens